# If post-format == 'gallery' conditional

Tags: post-formats

I'm working on trying to get my homepage template to display post-format 'gallery' a little different than the other formats but having no luck so far.

Here is a snippet 'inside the loop' that shows what I am trying to accomplish. Basically saying if post-format = 'aside' do x, elseif post-format is gallery, then I want to show a thumbnail, else just content.

```
<div class="entry">
    <?php

    if ( has_post_format( 'aside' , $post_id )) {
        the_excerpt(__('Continue Reading &rarr;', 'wptumble-fluid'));

    } elseif ( has_post_format( 'gallery' , $post_id )) {

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                // use the thumbnail ("featured image")
                $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); 
        } else {
            $attachments = get_children( array(
                'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
                'numberposts' => 1)
            );
            foreach ( $attachments as $thumb_id => $attachment )
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumb_id, 'thumbnail' ); 
            }
    } else {
            if ( $fluidtheme_options['fluid_post_content'] == "content" ) the_content(__('Continue Reading &rarr;', 'wptumble-fluid')); else the_excerpt();
    }

        wp_link_pages( $page_link_args );
    ?>

</div><!-- /.entry -->
```

The aside part works, as does the final option which checks the theme options page. The only thing not working is my elseif statement where I want it to grab the post attachment.

Probably just doing my php wrong, but this is the closest I can seem to come up with. Still in the learning process.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's an easy fix! The first argument in `has_post_format()` is a string in the format `post-format-{type}`, e.g. `post-format-aside`, or `post-format-gallery`, etc.

So, e.g., change this:

```
has_post_format( 'aside' , $post_id )
```

To this:

```
has_post_format( 'post-format-aside' , $post_id )
```

Wash, rinse, and repeat for all uses of `has_post_format()`.

**EDIT**

Given your example code, I would even suggest another potential option, combining `get_template_part()` and `get_post_format()`.

If you create template part files `entry-aside.php` and `entry-gallery.php`, along with a default, `entry.php`, then:

1) Move this code to `entry-aside.php` (and remove unsupported parameters):

```
the_excerpt();
```

2) Move this code to `entry-gallery.php`:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    // use the thumbnail ("featured image")
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); 
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
        'numberposts' => 1)
    );
    foreach ( $attachments as $thumb_id => $attachment )
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumb_id, 'thumbnail' ); 
}
```

3) Move this code to `entry.php`

```
if ( $fluidtheme_options['fluid_post_content'] == "content" ) the_content(__('Continue Reading &rarr;', 'wptumble-fluid')); else the_excerpt();
```

4) Replace that entire if/else conditional block with this:

```
get_template_part( 'entry', get_post_format() );
```

Now, it might be overkill for your current use case - but the advantage is that, if in the future you decide to support other post format types, you simply have to add `entry-{type}.php`, and your template will already be set up to support it! For example, if you add support for quotes, simply add `entry-quote.php`, with whatever appropriate code, and you don't have to change any existing code.

Comment: thank you, both solutions work great, no idea which to pick as winner, need option to select both

Comment: I don't think either one of us will fuss one way or the other. :) Just FYI: I added to my answer another idea for you to consider.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. I was just searching through stack for post-format archive pages, found this 'taxonomy_post_format-post-format-gallery.php' Your solution should make this much easier. I know they are not directly related, but close enough... I do indeed plan on having separate styles for both single and archive post-formats.

Comment: `the_excerpt()` doesn't take any argument.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use get_post_format for this:

```
if ( 'gallery' == get_post_format() ) {
    print 'TACO PARTY!!!';
}
```

Comment: thnx Michael, have 2 diff options, both work, not sure which is more efficient, has or get post format, either way I am happy